# Yii: Naming relations and fields

Tags: yii, naming-conventions

I wrote some Yii code with the same name for a DB field and a relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'kin' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Kin', 'kin'),
        'child' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Child', 'child'),
    );
}
```

Now I understand that this is wrong, because relations "cover" over field attributes and queries like `$this->child` to get child ID do not work.

My question: Which naming scheme would you suggest for DB fields and for relations?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I'd avoid naming your primary key after the table. It makes this kind of statement difficult to read. I always name my primary keys something like childId or kinId; that way it's clear what field you're talking about.

I think there is no hard and fast rules about naming, except to use what makes sense in your context. For something like this, assuming I've understood your table structure correctly, I'd be inclined to go for this:
Table 1: kin
Primary key: kinId

Table 2: child
Primary key: childId
Foreign key from table kin: fkKinId

Then, assuming that one kin can have many children, your relation in the Kin model becomes:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'children' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Child', 'fkKinId'),
    );
}
```

You can then call the child model for your kin using $this->children if you're inside the Kin model.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If it did, perhaps you could accept the answer please. Many thanks.